# Find which range of time have the most records

Tags: sql, time, max

How can I know which range of time have the most records? It can be every 4 minutes, every 31 minutes or even every 9 seconds.

Example for table:

```
Id  Time    Name
1   10:35   Dan
2   11:47   Eli
3   10:00   Mike
4   12:02   George
5   10:02   Jack
6   09:58   Stephan
7   11:25   Tony
8   11:34   Daniel
9   11:11   Joe
10  10:59   Tanya
```

It can be every 60 minutes (result would be 10:59) but it can be every 5 minutes (which the result is: 09:58).

The function calls the query gets 1 parameter - span time (in seconds), 300 for example (5 minutes).

The query returns in this case: {3, 09:58} (3 records from 09:58 in 5 minutes (09:58, 10:00, 10:02). I don't know at all how to do it.

I know how to find the most records in a hour:

```
SELECT TOP 1 HOUR(TIME) AS TIME,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Records
GROUP BY Hour(TIME)
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Any known pattern how to do it?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you have another column with timestamps, a schema which has both "From" and "To" columns, or just one timestamp column called "Time"? Also, what records? You're looking for the interval with the most records or the timestamp which has most records?

Comment: The most helfpul thing that you can do is give us more details and **expected sample output**, based on the data you provide in your question.

Comment: And foremost, you need to show us what queries you have tried to resolve this, before asking us, otherwise you risk your question being downvoted or even worse, to get it **closed**. You should take note of everything I have commented and make sure you add all of these elements next time you ask a question.

Comment: The function calls the query gets 1 parameter - span time (in seconds), 300 for example (5 minutes). The query returns in this case: {3, 09:58} (3 records from 09:58 in 5 minutes (09:58, 10:00, 10:02). I don't know at all how to do it. I know how to find the most records in a hour: SELECT Top 1 HOUR(Time) as time,COUNT(*) as count FROM Records GROUP BY Hour(Time) ORDER BY count DESC

Comment: What database system are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres etc.?

Comment: I am using Sql Server

Comment: Well, then you have the answer below.

Comment: What version of SQL Server, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming you're using SQL Server or something that uses T-SQL, the following query should work for you:

```
DECLARE @interval INT
SET @interval = 300

SELECT t.TIME,
    (
        SELECT count(*) AS cnt
        FROM timetable
        WHERE TIME >= t.TIME
                AND TIME <= DATEADD(second, @interval, t.TIME)
        ) cnt
FROM timetable t
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

If you want just the first record (the timestamp with most records in the time interval), just use `TOP 1` to filter the query, like so:

```
DECLARE @interval INT
SET @interval = 300

SELECT TOP 1 t.TIME,
    (
        SELECT count(*) AS cnt
        FROM timetable
        WHERE TIME >= t.TIME
                AND TIME <= DATEADD(second, @interval, t.TIME)
        ) cnt
FROM timetable t
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Here is a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1450/10) with how the query works.

If you're not using a RDBMS that uses T-SQL, then the principle is the same and you'll most likely just have to replace the `DATEADD()` function with what is appropriate correspondent for the RDBMS you're using.

Also, **note that this query will work only if you provide the time interval in seconds** and not other time intervals (minutes, hours etc.)

Comment: You [really shouldn't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Especially on SQL Server.  (This actually applies to all positive, contiguous-range types - everything but integers.  It's a property of how numbers are represented, not something specific to the actual db type...).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I modified my answer, so there's no more `BETWEEN`.

Comment: ...Sorry, I should have been a little more specific - the real problem with `BETWEEN` is that it uses an inclusive upper-bound (`<=`) instead of an exclusive one (`<`).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Ok, noted. But I think OP actually needs inclusive operators. Just take for example the `09:58` example and the time interval. This includes the `09:58` time and the following times, so it's inclusive. So, `BETWEEN` would have also worked, while the exclusive operator would not match the **sample expected result**.

Comment: No, you don't.  It goes like this: Say you have a timestamp starting on the hour.  You wish to count the number of rows for each hour.  So you add an hour to your starting time for the top of the limit, and count.  If it's inclusive, you include the starting row of the next set (counted twice, once for each group), which throws of the counts.  If it's exclusive, it's only counted once.  The OP's sample set works properly in this case: `09:58 + 5 MINUTES = 10:03` - `10:02` is the last element being counted.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse But the OP didn't mention anything about it being inclusive or exclusive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67164/discussion-between-radu-gheorghiu-and-clockwork-muse).

Comment: That's the answer. I didn't know I can use select in select line

Comment: @AviCohen Well, now you know.